# Redirect a URL to another URL

Tags: dns, internet

I use Linux (Arch) as my daily operating system. I believe I'm too addicted to YouTube, so I would like to redirect all requests to youtube.com to wikipedia.org so that when I write youtube.com in the address bar it takes me to Wikipedia. How could I achieve this?

My first thoughts were to use the `hosts` file, but I soon discovered that couldn't work.

Perhaps this could be achieved with something like **dnsmasq**?

Comment: You could install a local proxy server and run your traffic via it. [`squid`](https://www.jujens.eu/posts/en/2017/Jun/09/redirect-url-squid/) would be my suggestion. Also see: [Archwiki on `squid`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Squid)